# Own shortcuts in Word for options

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

What's the best practice to set/define a shortcut in Microsoft Word to change a specific option in an option dialog like "Paragraph" or "Font"? I want to swap e.g. the option to hold a paragraph together with a shortcut instead of always navigating in the paragraph dialog with many clicks.

Comment: Record a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the Ribbon, then select Customize Ribbon

Expand the Home Group

Click New Group

Expand your new group

On the "Choose Commands from" drop-down, select "All Commands."

Scroll down to the P's.

Highlight "Para Keep With Next"

Click "Add"

The Paragraph Keep with Next command is now available on your ribbon.

You can rename both your Custom Group as well as the command you added. Sometimes Word names are cryptic or too long, so whatever shorthand works for you will be fine.

On my home ribbon, I have Clear Formats (wipes out all formatting in the selected paragraph and resets it to normal), Para Keep With Next, Change Case, Pictures (opens the Add Picture browser), Cross-reference (opens the cross-reference dialog), Convert Text to Table, Header Row (sets the selected table row as a header).

Once you beat Word into submission and stop Microsoft from deciding on your workflow and what commands are needed for someone who actually writes instead of churning out memos and mail merges, the mechanical process of your tasks get easier.

I also highly recommend taking a look at AddinTool dot com. They make a rather handy add-on that can restore the old MS Word menu system which makes all Word commands available from a real menu instead of being buried under the ribbon or not being presented at all. There is at least one other add-on that replaces the menu system, but I don't have their company name handy. I've been using AddinTool's version since 2007 (except when IT locks down my system and won't let me have it) and I also use it on my home PC.

Comment: Perfect! The tip with the ribbon made my day :-)

Comment: I'm glad it cheered your day!